# Changing the positions of force layout d3 dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

How can i change the layout shape of the force layout d3? Here i'm getting the x and y position in the json data. Consider when i click a button then the layout have to change to round in shape dynamically as in the image.
[image]

Comment: You have to go through each node and change the x/y positions individually, how do you want them laid out ?

Comment: I want to laid radially. Similar like this http://bl.ocks.org/vlandham/5087480

Comment: But how can i manipulate the X and Y in the existing JSON ?

Comment: you've just provided a link to one that provides code. Just read and understand that, the answer is there

Comment: Ok AJ I will try. Each time you are helping me out :) Seems like my old frd :) . Let me try

Comment: Haha no worries, I need to learn more myself so helping people on here helps a lot :))

Comment: try something similar tot my code, so put your nodes on a straight line to see how it works then it gets complicated as angles and radians come into play but shouldnt be too difficult

Comment: getting 'each' of undefined. Should i use forEach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74803/discussion-between-aj-91-and-fekkydev).

Answer (score 0):

Just seen you want it circular, so, you have to iterate through each node and set the positions. So for example:

```
Nodes.each(function(d, i){          
            d.x = i * 50;
            d.y = 100;
        });
```

This will put each node on the same line with 50px between each one. Now for a circle you'll probably have to use `(Pi*r)^2` and work with that.

So go through each one, set the position based on 'i' (i.e what space it is in the nodes array) and you're done :)

From the example you posted you just need to apply this function to your code :

```
function radial(data, index, alpha) {
    var startAngle = 30;
    var radius = 350;
    var currentAngle = startAngle + (30 * index);
    var currentAngleRadians = currentAngle * D2R;

    var radialPoint = {
      x: 500 + radius * Math.cos(currentAngleRadians),
      y: 250 + radius * Math.sin(currentAngleRadians)
    };

    var affectSize = alpha * 0.1;

    data.x += (radialPoint.x - data.x) * affectSize;
    data.y += (radialPoint.y - data.y) * affectSize;


}
```

And when you call it you pass your nodes data (JSON file to it)